# Image losing quality after upload to FTP server using PHP

Tags: php, ftp, image-uploading

I made a script to upload an image to an FTP server but the image is losing quality - and seems like it only has 256 pixels

My HTML:

```
<form action="upload_image_travel.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input name="file" type="file" accept="image/jpeg"/>Upload foto in folderul travel/imagini/ pentru ARTICOL
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload File in TRAVEL" />
    </form>
```

And my upload.php:

```
$ftp_server = "xxxxx";
$ftp_user_name = "xxxxx";
$ftp_user_pass = "xxxxx";
$destination_file = "/public_html/travel/imagini/" . $_FILES['file']['name'];
$source_file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true); 

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 

// check connection
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { 
    echo "FTP connection has failed!";
    echo "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user $ftp_user_name"; 
    exit; 
} else {
    echo "Connected to $ftp_server, for user $ftp_user_name";
}

// upload the file
if (ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_ASCII)) {
   echo "successfully uploaded $destination_file\n";
   header('Location: administrator/admin_index_travel.php');
} else {
   echo "There was a problem while uploading $destination_file\n";
}

// close the FTP stream 
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

Comment: Try `FTP_BINARY` instead of `FTP_ASCII`

Comment: How many pixels do you have on the client side before the upload?

Comment: i change into the `FTP_BINARY` and now works... ithanks man

Answer (score -4, accepted):

maybe it should be FTP_BINARY? not ascii?

Comment: you are write... was the problem in this statement... thank you